# Unable to locate the package. Linux command error

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, command

Whenever Im trying to install something in linux through the terminal its saying that its unable to loacte the package.
I even have updated the code lines in the /etc/apt/source.list.
nut again Im getting the same response!

```
┌──(rootkali)-[/etc]
└─# apt-get install mysql                                              127 ⨯
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
```

this is what Im getting!

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about Linux install issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from depeneding on the Repository source. You can try following

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Then search for the package using apt-cache.

sudo apt-cache search mysql | grep mysql | more
You will have couple of results and you can choose appropriate one for you. You might need the client or Server (depends on your needs). The result is as below:

```
mysql-server - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
mysql-server-5.5 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
mysql-client - MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
```

mysql-server - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
mysql-client-5.5 - MySQL database client binaries
Once you figure out what version of sql is available. You can install it with apt-get.

sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
Hope this helps. Alos this is the official Mysql Community page to download MySQL Server for different platforms.